# What defines the price of puggle drops?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

The puggle drops seem to cost more and more over time...

What defines how much it costs to drop a pug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two factors in the price. The first is the Level of the item (or items) you are having shipped. A Level 2 item being shipped costs way less than a Level 8 item, for example. The other factor I have possibly seen (although I am not sure if I am right) is your Level - the higher it is, lower level items will get a price hike.

Also, when getting two or three items shipped, the total cost is equal to how much it'd cost to play if you did each seperatly, added together.